# How do I make a drawing repeat on canvas?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

I need to make some repetitions but I'm not really sure how to make it, when the user clicks the button "Part one" it should display the pig drawing every 100 pixels to the right and when the user clicks parte two it should display a circle of pigs in the center of the canvas but it has to delete the function that part one did.
can someone help me please?

```js
"use strict";
let ctx;


function setup() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

  drawPig();
}

function drawPig() {
ctx.fillStyle = "pink"
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(25, 40, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(40, 25, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillRect(45, 20, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(42, 18, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI); 
    ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(35, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 60);
  ctx.moveTo(35, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(35, 62);
  ctx.moveTo(15, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(5, 60);
  ctx.moveTo(15, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(15, 60);
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Repetitions</title>
   <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="setup()">
    <h1>Repeat</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
    <br>
    <button onclick="firstPart"> First Part</button>
    <button onclick="secondPart">Second Part</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate):

```
for (int i=0; i<ctx.canvas.width; i+=100){
    for (int j=0; j=ctx.canvas.height; j+=100){
        ctx.translate(i,j);
        drawPig();
        ctx.translate(-i,-j);
    }
}
```

This will draw a pig every 100 px. You could use a similar function do draw something else.

As for clearing the canvas, you can use `ctx.clearRect(clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` to set all pixels to 0 alpha black. You can also use this function to clear only part of the canvas if you so desire.